# SwiftUI - How can I call a Function in my View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI/Swift for a week now, and I love it. Now I have a problem. I want to call a Function from my View, but I get this Error

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

This is the Code:

```
struct testView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("TextBox")
            Text("SecondTextBox")
            self.testFunction()
        }
    }
    
    func testFunction() {
        print("This is a Text.")
    }
    
}
```

I don't get it. In other languages its much simpler and could work that way. Can anybody help me please? Swift is pretty new to me :D

Comment: It is not clear what are you going to do with that function and at which moment, because in context of body mostly expected only views. So would you elaborate more?

Comment: Im just playing around with SwiftUI. I tried to execute a for in the View, but I couldn't. Is there a way to execute functions or for's in a View?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Meanwhile here are the places (not all) where/how you can call a function

```
    init() {
        self.testFunction()     // non always good, but can
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.testFunction()            // 1)
        return VStack {
            Text("TextBox")
               .onTapGesture {
                  self.testFunction()    // 2)
               }
            Text("SecondTextBox")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.testFunction()     // 3)
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.testFunction()     // 4)
        }
    }
```

... and so on

Comment: ah okay, I understand it now a little bit better. But why is there a "return" before the VStack?

Comment: because `body` is computed property with opaque return type, so in this case requires explicit indication of what is returned to determine type.

Comment: @yama_HD Only functions with a single statement can omit the return keyword https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID607

Comment: Non of them is not working

Answer (score 4):

An additional method:

Testing with Swift 5.8, you can also stick in a `let _ = self.testFunction()`.

eg
(this is extra-contrived so that it's possible to see the effect in Preview, because print() doesn't happen in Preview, at least for me)

```
import SwiftUI

class MyClass {
    var counter = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var myClass: MyClass
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("TextBox counter = \(myClass.counter)")
            
            // v--------------------------------------------
            //
            let _ = self.testFunction()  // compiles happily
            //  self.testFunction()      // does not compile
            //
            // ^--------------------------------------------

            Text("TextBox counter = \(myClass.counter)")
        }
    }
    
    func testFunction() {
        print("This is a Test.")
        myClass.counter += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(myClass: MyClass())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Swift 5.3 and Xcode 12.4**

I use a little extension to debug inside the Views (VStack in the example), e.g. to inspect a geometryReader.size. It could be used to call any function in the View as follows:

**NOTE: For debugging purposes only. I don't recommend including code like this in any production code**

```
VStack {
    Text.console("Hello, World")
    Text("TEXT"
}

extension Text {
    static func console<T>(_ value: T) -> EmptyView {
        print("\(value)")
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

This will print "Hello, World" to the console.....

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason, when writing in swift UI (iOS Apps), that there is a View protocol that needs to be followed. Calling functions from inside the structure is not compliant with the protocol.

The best thing you can do is the .on(insertTimeORAction here).

[Read more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onappear(perform:))

Comment: The link provided in the answer above does not work.  Please update it.